# Two <iframe> in same html file isn't working properly

Tags: html, iframe

I tried to add two local html file (as frame, inside one html code) in two different iframe, but its not working. Output showing the same html file in both frame.[I guess, screenshot will help to understand my problem]

Here my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<h1>Frame1:</h1>
<iframe src="frame1.html" frameborder="1" width="100%" height="250px" name="frame1">
</iframe>
<br /><br /><br />

<h2>Frame 2:</h2>
<iframe src="frame2.html" frameborder="1" width="100%" height="250px" name="frame2">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

frame1.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<h2>This is a separate frame than others</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

frame2.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<h3>Frame 3:</h3>
<iframe src="" frameborder="1" width="90%" height="180px">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot, describing my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHcR7.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just try copy pasting your code in 3 different file in same folder, and i got what you need to have

Maybe this is a cache problem. Have you try to clear your cache browser?
[image: See my result and files here]

Comment: I am also facing problem with file location in iframe. When a tried to use a local file from a different folder inbiframe tag, its not working. Have you any solution of it?? like––<iframe src="../newfolder/Svg.html" framevorder="0" width="100%" height="250px"></iframe>

Comment: well, if file are in same folder, just write the name of the file in src="". Otherwise, you can write relative or absolute path. see https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths to know what is the difference. If you like th solution, upvote it, or flag it at solve.

Comment: I am new here, sir. I don't have enough reputation of giving upvote. Don't even know how to flag solved. I, um, just checked the mark into green beside the upvote icon. Is that what you meant? Otherwise, sorry.